# RobotFramework Oracle DB Connection Issue

Tags: jdbc, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I'm trying to check if the oracle DB connection using the Keyword:

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params
```

Following libraries are imported:

1. `Database Library`
2. `JayDeBe API`

This this is the connection string used:

```
'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//DBHostname:Port/DBName', ['user', 'pass']
```

We do not get any response that can identify if the connection is established or rejected.

We see this message in RIDE:

> 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//DBHostName:Port/DBName', ['user', 'pass']
>
> 20170927 17:07:54.438 :  INFO : Executing : Connect To Database Using Custom Params : jaydebeapi.connect(db_api_2.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//DBHostName:Port/DBName', ['user', 'pass']))

Can someone please help us?

Comment: did you try executing a query after the connection? Perhaps the module simply doesn't output anything to confirm you were connected.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer to your question, in order to help other people who may have the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution: In our case we have python 2.7(32bit) therefore we need the following: 
1. Oracle Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows (32-bit). you can download it from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html

2. Set the variable path in environment variable for the Oracle Instant client.
3. Download cx_Oracle API (32bit- cx_Oracle-6.0.2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl (md5) ) from the location:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/
4. Open command prompt and run: pip install cx_Orcle --upgrade
5. Open the RIDE and use the following keyword:

Connect To Database Using Custom Params  cx_Oracle  'user', 'password', 'DBHOSTNAME:PORT/DBNAME'